# How to add custom tags to powerpoint slides using OpenXml in c#

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to add custom tags to PowerPoint slides using OpenXml component in c#.
But after adding the tags dynamically, the presentation gets corrupted and is causing the powerpoint to stop working.

Following is the code I'm using for adding the tags:

```
 public static void AddSlideTag(string presentationPath, string tagValue)
    {

        using (PresentationDocument presentation = PresentationDocument.Open(presentationPath, true))
        {
            var presPart = presentation.PresentationPart;

            // Copy each slide in the source presentation, in order, to 
            // the destination presentation.
            var slideIndex = 0;

            foreach (var openXmlElement in presPart.Presentation.SlideIdList)
            {
                var slideId = (SlideId)openXmlElement;

                // Create a unique relationship id.
                var sp = (SlidePart)presPart.GetPartById(slideId.RelationshipId);


                    //create userDefinedTag
                    Tag slideObjectTag = new Tag() { Name = "CustomTag", Val = tagValue};
                    UserDefinedTagsPart userDefinedTagsPart1 = sp.AddNewPart<UserDefinedTagsPart>();
                    if (userDefinedTagsPart1.TagList == null)
                        userDefinedTagsPart1.TagList = new TagList();

                    userDefinedTagsPart1.TagList.Append(slideObjectTag);

                    //add tag to CustomerDataList element
                    var id = sp.GetIdOfPart(userDefinedTagsPart1);

                    if (sp.Slide.CommonSlideData == null)
                    {
                        sp.Slide.CommonSlideData = new CommonSlideData();
                    }
                    if (sp.Slide.CommonSlideData.CustomerDataList == null)
                        sp.Slide.CommonSlideData.CustomerDataList = new CustomerDataList();
                    CustomerDataTags tags = new CustomerDataTags();
                    tags.Id = id;
                    sp.Slide.CommonSlideData.CustomerDataList.AppendChild(tags);


                slideIndex++;
                sp.Slide.Save();
            }
            presPart.Presentation.Save();
        }
    }
```

It seems like the xml of the slides is broken after executing this code, but I cannot figure out what is the problem.

Does anyone know what is wrong with the code above, or what is causing the powerpoint to gets corrupted after running this code? Am I missing something here?

I'm using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.2.5 package.

Comment: have you used openxml sdk productivity tool to check the corrupt file? It will show you what's wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about openxml sdk productivity tool before, but I will definitely start using it. The issue was that on some slides I have added two custom tags and they were added on wrong way. I was creating  separate UserDefinedTagsPart parts instead of appending the tags into the taglist of the tag.xml