# OpenXML SDK: How to get "Tag" (p:tag) val of a PowerPoint shape?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk

I need to check all tags on all shapes on all slides. I can select each shape, however I can't see how to get the shape's tags.

For the given DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape, how can I get the "val" of the tag with name="MOUNTAIN"
In my shape, the tag rId is in this structure:  p:sp > p:nvSpPr > p:cNvPr > p:nvPr > p:custDataList > p:tags

I'm guessing my code needs to do these steps:

```
• Get the rId of the p:custDataLst p:tags
• Look up the "Target" file name in the slideX.xml.rels file, based on the rId
• Look in the root/tags folder for the "Target" file
• Get the p:tagLst p:tags and look for the p:tag with name="MOUNTAIN"
   <p:tagLst
       <p:tag name="MOUNTAIN" val="Denali"/>
   </p:tagLst>
```

Here is how my code iterates through shapes on each slide:

```
for (int x = 0; x < doc.PresentationPart.SlideParts.Count(); x++)
{
   SlidePart slide = doc.PresentationPart.SlideParts.ElementAt(x);
   ShapeTree tree = slide.Slide.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree;                        
   IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape> slShapes = slide.Slide.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape>();
   foreach (DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape shape in slShapes)
   {
      //get the specified tag, if it exists
   }
}
```

I see an example of how to add tags: [How to add custom tags to powerpoint slides using OpenXml in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093093/how-to-add-custom-tags-to-powerpoint-slides-using-openxml-in-c-sharp)
But I can't figure out how to read the existing tags.

So, how do I get the shape's tags with c#?

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<UserDefinedTagsPart> userDefinedTagsParts = shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties.CustomerDataList.CustomerDataTags<UserDefinedTagsPart>();
foreach (UserDefinedTagsPart userDefinedTagsPart in userDefinedTagsParts)
{}
```

but Visual Studio says "ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties does not contain a definition for CustomerDataList".

From the OpenXML Productivity Tool, here is the element tree:

[image: TagsElementTree]

Comment: Strong suggestion: download the OpenXML SDK tool, and "reflect" one of your files: https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You and I seem to be working on similar problems. I'm struggling with learning the file format. The following code is working for me, I'm sure it can be optimized.

```
        public void ReadTags(Shape shape, SlidePart slidePart)
        {
            NonVisualShapeProperties nvsp = shape.NonVisualShapeProperties;
            ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties nvdp = nvsp.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties;
            IEnumerable<CustomerDataTags> data_tags = nvdp.Descendants<CustomerDataTags>();

            foreach (var data_tag in data_tags)
            {
                UserDefinedTagsPart shape_tags = slidePart.GetPartById(data_tag.Id) as UserDefinedTagsPart;

                if (shape_tags != null)
                {
                    foreach (Tag tag in shape_tags.TagList)
                    {
                        Debug.Print($"\t{nvsp.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Name} tag {tag.Name} = '{tag.Val}");
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
```

Comment: That works to get the tag if I hardcode the correct rId. shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.NonVisualDrawingProperties.Id may be the wrong element. I think it should be shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties.CustomerDataList.CustomerDataTags.id, but I can't figure out how to get that id. How can I?

Comment: How might I get the rId of shape.NonVisualShapeProperties.ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties.CustomerDataList.CustomerDataTags.id? Visual Studio says "ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties does not contain a definition for CustomerDataList"

Answer (score 1):

I've spent a lot of time with OpenXML .docx and .xlsx files ... but not so much with .pptx.

Nevertheless, here are a couple of suggestions that might help:

1. If you haven't already done so, please downoad the OpenXML SDK Productivity Tool to analyze your file's contents.  It's currently available on GitHub:

   https://github.com/dotnet/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5
2. You might simply be able to "grep" for items you're looking for.

   EXAMPLE (Word, not PowerPoint... but the same principle should apply):

   ```
       using (doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
        {
            // Init OpenXML members
            mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;
            body = mainPart.Document.Body;
            ...
            foreach (var text in body.Descendants<Text>())
            {
                if (text.Text.Contains(target))
                    ...
   ```

Comment: Q: Did you look at the C# code generated using the [Reflection] button?

Comment: I did try the Productivity tool, but 'reflect' only gives simple code, like Tag tag1 = new Tag(){ Name = "MOUNTAIN", Val = "Denali" };  and CustomerDataTags customerDataTags1 = new CustomerDataTags(){ Id = "rId1" };. I did add the element tree above.

Comment: Q: Were you able to try a `foreach (var tags in body.Descendants<...>)` loop like I suggested above?  PS: My challenge is that for lack of a an example .pptx, I can't reproduce the problem myself.

Comment: I've tried using .Descendants<UserDefinedTagsPart> and similar, but it is complicated by the tags being in a different xml file from the slide connected by rels.

Comment: If you want to create a sample .pptx: in "Script Lab" (the Office.js add-in), use the "Work with tags" snippet. Select a shape, then click "Add shape tag".